# Dynamo Db Accelerator should reduce the response time to microseconds

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb-dax

i am using aws lamda function and dynamodb and api gateway for my application

and making a load test using Apache bench and i had run the test successfully

### for 1000 request and 100 concurrency

and here is the result

### Test #1

Concurrency Level:      100

Time taken for tests:   0.920 seconds

Complete requests:      1000

Failed requests:        0

Requests per second:    1086.60 [#/sec] (mean)

### Time per request:       92.030 [ms] (mean)

Time per request:       0.920 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)

After that i added DAX (dynamodb accelerator) to reduce the response time to microseconds as expected

but i got same results

### Test #2

Concurrency Level:      100

Time taken for tests:   0.853 seconds

Complete requests:      1000

Failed requests:        0

Requests per second:    1172.12 [#/sec] (mean)

### Time per request:       85.315 [ms] (mean)

Time per request:       0.853 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)

Answer (score 0):

Lambda and API Gateway have significant overhead themselves, which likely accounts for most of that 85ms. The only part that DAX can speed up is reading from DynamoDB.

For example, say a regular read (GetItem) from DynamoDB takes 2.5ms, and a cached read from DAX takes 500µs, and your Lambda does 5 sequential GetItems. In that case DynamoDB would take 12.5ms, and DAX would require 2.5ms, saving 10ms of time in the Lambda - but you still have to pay the cost of API Gateway and Lambda, which could easily be 50+ ms.

(I recommend reading up on [Amdahl's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law) if you're not familiar with it to understand the limitations of performance optimization.)

It may still make sense to use DAX for your use case because it may let you reduce your DynamoDB provisioned throughput or on demand requests, but when using Lambda the latency improvement will only be noticeable if each Lambda makes many requests.